# Atomic increment or insert in Firebird SQL

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I need to increment an existing value by N, or insert N if the key doesn't exist.  I was looking for an atomic command, but Merge and Update Or Insert don't offer this (increment or insert).  Is there a better solution than this pseudo code

```
UPDATE T SET T.COL=T.COL+N WHERE KEY=K;
If (nothing updated) INSERT INTO T(KEY,COL) VALUE(K,N);
If (duplicate exception) UPDATE T SET T.COL=T.COL+N WHERE KEY=K;
```

Comment: Please show the merge statement you tried, and explain (or demonstrate) why you think it isn't 'atomic'.

Comment: I didn't say that Merge wasn't atomic, what I was trying to state was that Merge and Update-Or-Insert ARE atomic, but don't perform the task (increment by N or insert N) that I require.  I would love if I was wrong, since a single atomic command would be preferred.

Comment: You do not show your commands, you do not show what wrong results you observe instead of expected, how can we ever guess when could go wrong???

Comment: pseudo-code too `UPDATE OR INSERT T SET K.KEY=K, T.COL=N + COALESCE (  (SELECT COL FROM T WHERE KEY=K), 0)  WHERE KEY=K;`

Comment: Also `select first(1) * from ( select key,col+N as col from T where key=K UNION ALL select K, N from rdb$database)` - and then merge with it.

Comment: Arioch 'The, can you post your first comment as a solution so I can comment on it there?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `merge` can do what you want, so I want to see what you tried, so I can tell whether I'm wrong or not.

Comment: Mark, what I posted is what I have been using, since I didn't think of what Arioch suggested.  Arioch 'The, is that the biblical or the Melnibonéan Arioch?

Comment: @RickDeBay Melnibonean, I was quite spirited in mid-1990s, and then this nickname turned to be very distinct (like, in 20 years I only twice met similar nick in RuNet), so I stuck with it. When u've got a distinct quasi-unique token, there is little reason to look for something better :-)  PS. I didn't even know there is some Arioch in The Bible, I thought mr. Moorcock invented the name :-D

Comment: And the article thing, soon after registering on the first Russian free e-mail server, chat.ru now defunct, I naturally forgotten the password, so I had to register another one instead :-D ( as it was the first server of a kind, I had no alternative mailbox to do some password recovery)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [merge](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-dml-merge):

```
merge into mergetest as t
   using (select 1 as id, 2 as countcolumn from rdb$database) as src
       on t.id = src.id
   when matched then 
       update set t.countcolumn = t.countcolumn + src.countcolumn
   when not matched then 
       insert (id, countcolumn) values (src.id, src.countcolumn)
```

Of course under concurrent load this may still fail (eg two transaction inserting the same record, or two transactions updating the same record), so be prepared to retry your transaction.

Answer (score 0):

This is from the comment by Arioch 'The.  I was surprised, but it prepared.  I'll test it when I have time.  Whenever Arioch posts this as an answer I'll approve that so he can get the internet points.

```
UPDATE OR INSERT INTO T(K,C)
VALUES
  (:K,
    COALESCE(
      (SELECT T.C 
       FROM T
       WHERE T.K = :K), 0)   
   + :INCREMENT)
MATCHING (K);
```

Comment: u have two ":K" params, I would be wary about it. In SQL there are no names with parameters, all parameters are anonymous and go simply as #1, #2, #3, etc. When u use libraries with named parameters ( the ":name" pattern is typical for Delphi for example; some DotNet libs use "@name" convention, etc) the said library should keep the mapping "name -> number". Now, what would it do when you put the same name twice or more? Won't it confuse the library? I know for sure some Delphi libs get quite confused. So more safe (but tedious) would be to have like :K1 and :K2 independently